# natbib on memoir

Tags: memoir, natbib, apa-style, apa6, doi

I'm not able to modify the natbib on memoir.
For example I would like to have the long reference at first time and the & before the last author.
Moreover, I would like to have the bibliography in APA style and to show the doi.

Someone can help me please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,leqno, natbib, openbib, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[semicolon, longnamefirst] {natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{doi}
.
.
.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Here an example of citation: (Ward et al.,2008; Causer et al., 2014, 2013)

and an example of the references:

Eysenck, M. W. and Calvo, M. G. (1992).
Anxiety and Performance: The Processing Efficiency Theory.
Cognition & Emotion, 6(6):409–434.

thank you for the help

Comment: As always full (but minimal) examples, not sniplets. As far as I remember this is not memoir related. Additionally, is apalike even compatible with natbib?

Comment: I tried also with \bibliographystyle{apa}, the result is the same. I am using this template [https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-bristol-thesis-template/kzqrfvyxxcdm], but I would like to change the style of references